# Rails: undefined method `signed_id' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:casualID>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm on Ruby 2.4.1-rc2 and Rails 5.2.1 and I'm using active storage. File uploading is perfect, but when I try to recall a file download url with `rails_blob_path(user.avatar, disposition: "attachment", only_path: true)` or `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(c.allegati, only_path: true)`, it gives me this error:

```
NoMethodError at /profilepage
undefined method `signed_id' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::Many:0x00007f85c90dd170>
```

0x00007f85c90dd170 changes everytime I reload.

I searched here and on Google but no one has this issue, my ActiveStorage config is the standard config (except for S3 credentials).

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Edit: more code**

*show.html.erb*

```
  <% if @utente.sostitutore == "1" %>
  <h1 class="title is-3">Sostituzioni accettate</h1>
  <% b = Sostituzione.where(sostitutore: utente_corrente.id) %>
  <% if b.empty? %>
  <p>
  Nessuna sostituzione accettata
  </p>
  <br />
  <% else %>
        <% b.each do |c| %>
            <%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(c.allegati, only_path: true) %>

  <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

*model*

```
class Sostituzione < ApplicationRecord
   attr_accessor :termini
   has_many_attached :allegati
   has_many_attached :documentiudienza
end
```

**Edit2**: it resultes via debug empty despite it's being uploaded correctly.

**Solved**

Comment: What is the value of `c` and `c.allegati`? Also, can you provide more code to what you have done, like model, view, configuration file.

Comment: Hey, so that random Hex is id of the object in Ruby, it will change with each new instance that is created.

Comment: I think that you are calling the path on a collection instead of an item.  Try sending `first` to the c variable and let me know what you see.  If that works, you will need to iterate over the collection and call path on each one.
    
`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(c.first.allegati, only_path: true)`

Comment: @Austio with your code it gives me this error: undefined method `undefined method `first' for #<Sostituzione:0x00007f85c78a8a28>`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Now I'm providing more code :D

Comment: What I would suggest is, put a debugger, just before the line which is throwing the error, and print the values of `c` and `c.allegati` and update your OP with them.

Comment: I added more code, in 5 minutes I will add the result of debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! For multiple attachments (allegati in italian) there is @sostituzione.allegati.first etc.
I solved with this code:

```
<% @sostituzione.allegati.each do |allegato| %>
<div class="level">
  <%= link_to 'Scarica documento allegato', rails_blob_path(allegato, only_path: true), class: 'button is-primary is-big' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```